# Reputation League links not working if nobody got any reputation during the league period

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, reputation-leagues, broken-link

The link for sports site on SO is not working  here on https://stackexchange.com/leagues.

Other sites such as Stack Overflow are working it is displaying an error.

It says it is a server fault.

May be a bug therefore i have thought to report it here on meta.

https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/leagues/189/week/sports/2013-05-26

Thanks.

### **UPDATE: 27th May 2013**

As spotted by  Daniel Daranas the links for reputation league sports site

1. https://stackexchange.com/leagues/189/alltime/sports
2. https://stackexchange.com/leagues/189/year/sports
3. https://stackexchange.com/leagues/189/quarter/sports
4. https://stackexchange.com/leagues/189/month/sports

are working

the only problem is with the https://stackexchange.com/leagues/189/week/sports

### **UPDATE: 07th June 2013**

All the links for sports site are working now but as spotted by  [Daniel Daranas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181929/link-not-working-for-sports-users-on-http-stackexchange-com-leagues/181939#181939) there were other few links which were also broken. All of them have been fixed by now except for [SmugMug](http://smugmug.stackexchange.com/), where the following links are broken:

1. Smugmug [week](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/183/week/smugmug) reputation in Reputation League.
2. Smugmug [month](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/183/month/smugmug) reputation in Reputation League.

Its been so long the links are not working for the week page and for month page I just spotted in on June 4th.

### **UPDATE: 18th June 2013**

We have finally come to the conclusion (see [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181929/reputation-league-links-not-working-for-smugmug-fixed-for-sports-and-other-site/181939#comment565411_181939) to the answer below) that **a link to a Reputation League gives a 404 error if nobody has scored any reputation**. This happened in Smugmug in the last few weeks, until yesterday [someone](http://smugmug.stackexchange.com/users/167/doc-walker?tab=reputation) scored some reputation. Suddenly, the Smugmug weekly and monthly reputation league links are not broken anymore, but if from the [weekly](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/183/week/smugmug) league you go to the previous week ( https://stackexchange.com/leagues/183/week/smugmug/2013-06-09 ), that's another story: nobody scored any reputation during that week, so the link fails.

I updated the title to convey this conclusion.

Comment: Repo'd. From my exhaustive testing (i.e. randomly clicking on a few other sites), its *only* sports which is affected. Weird.

Comment: @Matt yes i have also tried some random testing by clicking on other sites by passing URL values like http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/sports nothing works for me.

Comment: It's the _Week_ page ( http://stackexchange.com/leagues/189/week/sports ) in the Sports league that doesn't work. Month ( http://stackexchange.com/leagues/189/month/sports ) and others do work. From Month league, if you click the Week tab it doesn't work, either, because it links to the same place.

Comment: @DanielDaranas yes you are *right* it is working for *month,year,all time* it is only not working for *week* i have added your inputs to the question

Comment: Also, the _past week_ league in Sports is working (http://stackexchange.com/leagues/189/week/sports/2013-05-19, compare to Poker  http://stackexchange.com/leagues/173/week/poker/2013-05-19); but not the _current_ week, which if in Poker is http://stackexchange.com/leagues/173/week/poker/2013-05-27 (working) should be something like http://stackexchange.com/leagues/189/week/sports/2013-05-27.

Comment: @DanielDaranas well spotted i think it will be fixed soon as the error page says the error is reported to the site hope it get fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: @DanielDaranas thanks for updating the question...

Comment: @NetStarter Congratulations for your well deserved Nice question badge! :)

Comment: thanks and same to you buddy for nice answer...i have accepted the answer as no other answer are required now..as the problem is fixed:)

Comment: For the record, the problem is _not_ fixed, as far as I know. It just disappeared because the circumstances under which it appears (nobody got any reputation during the league period) no longer existed.

Comment: @DanielDaranas understood the same problem occurs again for http://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/leagues/189/week/sports may be there must be other page than the *Oops! Something Bad Happened!* one...It will be much more helpful for others in such case

Comment: @NetStarter That is true. On Monday, when the week has just started, there are more chances that league pages don't work for the less visited sites (beacuse there has been less time for anyone to win reputation). I just upvoted one question about football (http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2767/soccer-field-size), so I guess the weekly reputation league will start working as soon as its data are refreshed.

Comment: @DanielDaranas ok i also had positive reputation changes for the day of the week but yet those are not refreshed waiting for the data to be refreshed...

Comment: Oops! The [user](http://sports.stackexchange.com/users/1455/jacob-jan-tuinstra) whose question I upvoted has reputation 180, less than 200, so he doesn't appear in the leagues. Therefore, I didn't "fix" anything. However, other people gained reputation, so the weekly league [link](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/189/week/sports) is working again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [W3C Link Checker](http://validator.w3.org/checklink) test executed on the [Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) page gives server side errors in the following seven links, which I have manually verified to be broken:

- https://stackexchange.com/leagues/185/week/martialarts
- https://stackexchange.com/leagues/183/week/smugmug
- https://stackexchange.com/leagues/68/week/writers
- https://stackexchange.com/leagues/215/week/patents
- https://stackexchange.com/leagues/189/week/sports
- https://stackexchange.com/leagues/219/week/robotics
- https://stackexchange.com/leagues/101/week/mechanics

### UPDATE: 07th June 2013

The above links are already fixed, except [Smugmug](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/183/week/smugmug) and, surprisingly, also its monthly league ([Smugmug monthly league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/183/month/smugmug)), as reported by NetStarter in the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181929/link-not-working-for-sports-users-on-http-stackexchange-com-leagues#comment557634_181939) below. I haven't run the W3C Link Checker again, though, to find possible new broken links.

Comment: +1 for the efforts taken to find out the links which are not working and also for the W3C Link Checker

Comment: The link for the sports is fixed now the other links are not yet fixed.

Comment: @NetStarter I see them all fixed now except Smugmug and Mechanics.

Comment: yes you are right thanks for raising a good point i am accepting your answer.

Comment: @NetStarter We're getting closer. Today I see them all fixed except Smugmug.

Comment: it is nice that all are fix except the Smugmug.

Comment: @NetStarter I came back today to check and Smugmug still doesn't work. This is becoming kind of addictive. Somehow, I'll miss it when all links work.

Comment: Smugmug link not fixed yet

Comment: The link is also not fixed today as well,thanks for offering bounty for the question.

Comment: Look What i found today - http://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/leagues/183/month/smugmug the month link is also not working

Comment: @NetStarter Well spotted. I updated my answer with these results.

Comment: @NetStarter I don't think that this question is answered yet. Since the bug still exist; mark it as unanswered for now. Many people might not notice the question otherwise.

Comment: @hjpotter92 To have this question appear as unanswered - should I delete my answer altogether? (Or move its contents to an edition of the Question, since they are more detailed information to it.)

Comment: Let me move the contents to the question i have un accepted the answer

Comment: @DanielDaranas i have updated my question title and body to point to the SmugMug issue

Comment: @NetStarter well done. I reformatted it a bit to make the currently broken links stand out more.

Comment: Bounty coming to close and the links are not yet fixed..:|

Comment: @NetStarter Apparently, nobody cares :-)

Comment: @DanielDaranas well said the "Sweet are the fruits of adversity".Well done buddy the links are finally fixed cheers...

Comment: @NetStarter Aha! We got something here! Observe the following: (1) One and _only_ one user ( http://smugmug.stackexchange.com/users/167/doc-walker?tab=reputation ) got reputation _yesterday_ in Smugmug, thus making the Week and Month leagues nonempty. (2) Noone else got reputation in the whole last month. (3) The _previous_ week league is still empty, because noone got reputation in the last month except for that user yesterday... So if you go to the Week league and click on Previous ( http://stackexchange.com/leagues/183/week/smugmug/2013-06-09 )... Guess what happens? :-)

Comment: @DanielDaranas whole things on there are just a lot interesting.May be the cause for the links broken was may be because of empty records...oh god how much more to come out from this...:)...it was a adventures thing.May be the page call should check for null or empty also...:p