# Why don't we get responses from bug reports?

Tags: discussion, feedback, bug-reports

Currently we have [1356 bug reports](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano+-%5Bstatus-*%5D) that are not closed, have zero answers and no [status-*] tag.

Why aren't we getting feedback from the DEV team about these reports? Has the team even noticed every single bug report? I fear not since [not even all bounty questions get noticed by the team certainly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180765/172011).

Even if the bug won't get fixed it would be nice to get a quick response to know what the team thinks about that.

Comment: I think Anna response to [this recent question on same topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180063/152859) sums it up nicely: *We try, but we could certainly do better*

Comment: Just to note: Currently we have [145 bug reports](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+%5Bstatus-*%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano) that are not closed, have zero answers and **have *status* tag**.

Comment: Shouldn't we be looking at that number in proportion to the total **9,310** [`[bug]`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) posts?  Also, I don't know if we should count the ones that have no upvotes, or that do have an applicable status tag. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[bug]+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano+-[status-completed]+-[status-declined]+-[status-norepro]+-[status-bydesign]+-[status-planned]+score%3A1

Comment: @BilltheLizard: And there are certainly also bug reports with (unhelpful) answers but not from the dev team. Even if the essence are only 1000 unanswered bugs or less - it could still be much better.

Comment: To pick just one example, this bug ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181929/147655 ) has one answer from me which helped in clarifying the problem, but did _not_ solve it at all. It should be considered [status-pending], but there is no such status tag.

Comment: @DanielDaranas There are [status-planned] and [status-deferred]

Comment: Note that _many_ of the devs seem to be working on Big Things, and don't spend much time on Meta. (also I think they have a rotation of Meta duty, but that's a guess). As such we don't have that many devs available for [status-complete]ing duty.

Comment: @Manishearth: Personally I would like to think DEVs spend a little time here every day to get what is going on on their network.

Comment: Why not see how many devs you can pick out [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users), @juergend? I count 5 on just the first page...

Comment: @Shog9: I was just refering to Manishearth statement that DEVs probably *don't spend much time on Meta*. It's really great that this is not the case like it seems.

Comment: Now [see what you've done](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a8Q2j.png)! ;)

Comment: Related (to some extent): [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306397)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We could do better than we do. It's not just the development team that should be patrolling for these, it's also the community team. It's going to take some time to go through the list, but I'm going to venture that it's not *quite* as long as it seems:

- The 'bug' tag is applied incorrectly when reporting intended behavior from time to time
- Some of these were likely duplicate reports that just went unnoticed, and have been subsequently fixed with a reply posted *elsewhere*

Keep in mind that we have well over 100 child meta sites, which the developers also  patrol along with us. We can't always count on bugs that aren't specific *just* to certain sites (like a styling glitch) to be migrated here to Meta SO.

This is also a bit of an issue when it comes to feature requests - something we've addressed by bringing quite a few open feature requests into a weekly meeting where we discuss them and pass some on to the developers with our notes and changes. We are trying to get more efficient overall.

We do our best to make ourselves as accessible as possible to the community. While yes, we do sort of stink sometimes at catching things that need our reply - a lot of other services at our scale have perfected the art of making themselves *very* difficult to reach. We don't want to be 'that guy'. We'd rather lag a bit than become more insular.

That said, if you notice something you reported not getting any attention (and you're certain it's not actively being discussed on another bug report) you can do the following things:

- Send the community team [an email](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact/other), show us the meta post and let us know it's still broken and driving you nuts
- Ping one of us [in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) (generally the fastest way, but pings sometimes get lost)

If you haven't noticed, [we're also hiring like crazy](https://stackexchange.com/about/hiring)! As new people come on board and begin filling the roles which have been gaps in our teams, our bandwidth and responsiveness will naturally increase. Part of the problem is simply not having enough hours in the day. I'm sure you've heard jokes about the management here being slave drivers, but they actually kind of insist that we go home and not work for a while *every day* if you can believe that.

Improvement should be coming in the near future, and thanks for the prod.

Comment: Two and half years later, have there been any improvements? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, so this explains it.  I have two posts here, both bug reports, both no response.  Why Bother?

Comment: @StephenRauch because some bugs are fixed. Some faster than others. So we have hope. It's not perfect, but it's working for years, and isn't really bad. Better than all other sites I know of, which don't have any such system to begin with. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, yea, but we don't invest nearly at much in those others sites. Do we?  Some acknowledgement would be nice.  I won't be back to meta...

Comment: @Stephen you really take it way too far. I mean, that's your choice, but if you'll just understand the process you'll feel much better. If you want to try, hit me up on chat.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, do I have enough rep for that here, or should we take this somewhere else?

Comment: @StephenRauch yes you need only 20 rep to chat. https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/721/shadows-den

Answer (score 11):

I think the only sane way to look at this is:

- questions tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
- not closed
- with zero answers
- ordered by votes descending
- not [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) (sadly [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) is still included, length of query restrictions)
- question score of 1 or greater

Basically, [**this query**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bbug%5d%20answers%3a0%20closed%3ano%20-%5bstatus-completed%5d%20-%5bstatus-declined%5d%20-%5bstatus-norepro%5d%20-%5bstatus-bydesign%5d%20-%5bstatus-planned%5d%20score%3a1). That's 1,104 results. The first 50 descend to score of 15. The second 50 descend to score of 12.

I think it's fair to ask the team to post some kind of response to any so-called "bug" with 20 or more question votes as a general policy. That's around 25 items based on the current list.

Comment: As a note: "Real" bugs sometimes don't get much attention and upvotes. It often depends on the time posted. So upvotes aren't an exact measure to get real/important bugs.

Comment: @juergend Well, if you consider that making a couple of passes similar how how Jeff suggests would put a big dent in it, then the bugs that managed to go without much notice become much easier to find. You just keep slicing off the top of the stack, which is what they're doing.