# What is the process for having a site's close threshold lowered?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, per-site-meta

Stack Overflow [now has a 3 close vote threshold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832/we-re-lowering-the-close-reopen-vote-threshold-from-5-to-3-for-good)

> We’re lowering the close/reopen vote threshold on Stack Overflow from 5 to 3.

Shog9 then made [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832/we-re-lowering-the-close-reopen-vote-threshold-from-5-to-3-for-good#comment743117_391832)

> Other sites can have [whatever threshold is most appropriate for them](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4687/cancelling-election-lets-try-something-else-testing-three-vote-question-clos)

I took that to heart and [started a Meta on DIY.SE](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/can-we-get-the-close-vote-threshold-lowered-to-3), since I figured that would be the first step for any community would be that. [Other sites have followed suit](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4314/should-am-reduce-the-close-vote-requirement-down-to-3-from-5). But then we wind up with

1. Post on Meta
2. ???
3. Close vote threshold lowered
4. <s>PROFIT</s> CLOSURE

What do we need to do once we have a rough community consensus?

Comment: I'd guess 2 would actually be to contact a CM (chat, e-mail) saying your community has decided it would like a particular setting changed, and ask them to actually do so, like [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186824/369802) suggests in the bottom half? If you can't do so yourself (not a mod), you could ask a mod to do so.

Comment: I wasnt aware of that change, thanks for your post, just asked my community if it's something they would want too, as I can see only positive value to that

Comment: It is relevant what [Catija mentioned](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2059/18078) in the request in Japanese.SE: _what I generally do is a one-month test and then we compare some stats before and after to see what impact the change had_. So I would expect these requests to go into a queue of sites where this will be tested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We've had the same [process and debate](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3260/12637) at Spanish Language. In the meantime, as the current moderator for the site I asked JNat in a private chat what should we do in order to get the vote count threshold effectively lowered, and he said:

> When you feel enough discussion has taken place, and a consensus was reached, just email us.

So step 2 would be just having a moderator for your site to contact the CMs by emailing them at the usual `community@...` or `team@...` addresses at StackExchange or StackOverflow dot com.

Comment: Note: Rather than emailing the CMs, mods can now escalate a meta post for staff attention simply by adding the [status-review] tag, [as explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/335251).